# array not a member of namespace::std

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, std, libstdc++

I am using g++ version 4.5.2 .

Although I have include array header file 
`#include <array>` it does not complain about the existence of the header file.

But when I do `std::array<char , 16>`,

the exception is thrown when I try to compile with g++

> "array not a member of namespace std"

I searched on the net and saw a suggestion somewhere to use `std::tr1::array<>`,

but that did not help either ?

Does someone know what the problem is ?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: exceptions are _not_ thrown at compile time. It's a plain old _error_.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with GCC 4.6 and later to have C++11 features and you need to set the right flag to `-std=C++0x` or in GCC 4.7 `-std=C++11`

Comment: GCC 4.5 (and even 4.4) did already support quite a few C++11 features, so saying that you need GCC 4.6+ for any C++11 features isn't quite correct.

Comment: Should it be in lower case ? -std=c++0x or in GCC 4.7 -std=c++11.